# Using a raspberry 4 as a remote access tool

Tags: wifi, remote, port-forwarding

I need to remote access a datalogger device placed on a remote location. The ISP does not provide static IP, so DDNS is required, I don't have a router with the feature, so I'm trying to set it up with a raspberry using raspbian.

Currently I've set up the raspberry connected to the internet via wi-fi and sharing the internet to the datalogger over eth cable.
The datalogger have a static ip and internet is getting to it properly, I've set up the ddns server and I can currently use it to connect to the raspberry using DDClient and a noip ddns.

Now I need to forward the ip that's on the eth to my remote access, so when I use my remote address it points me to the datalogger on its IP.

Here's where I got stuck, I've tried ssh tunnel, but I don't know how to work it out.
ssh -N-L "deviceport":"deviceip":80 localhost gives me a return that cannot connect to local port 22, I haven't found a workaround so far.

Comment: what does this mean exactly? ... `access a datalogger device`

Comment: `localhost` exists only inside the OS of a computer ... it does not extend to any hardware